# My App is crashing on android 11 when I store realm database locally in a folder?

Tags: java, android, database, realm

The app crashes on Android 11 when I am going to save realm database in local internal storage. The app is working in all other version but today I updated my app to android 11 and it's crashing.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process:  PID: 7882
io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. open() failed: Operation not permitted in io_realm_internal_Group.cpp line 210
    at io.realm.internal.Group.nativeWriteToFile(Native Method)
    
   
      private Realm realm;

      try {

        File file = new File(folderPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
      
        realm = new File(file, fileName);
       
        if (realm .exists()) {
            realm .delete();
        }
       
        realm.writeCopyTo(realm ); // crashing here in this line

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation I solved the issue by replacing getExternalStorageDirectory to context.getExternalFilesDir(); to save realm database locally in a folder for backup.

[See Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

Storage permission is completely changed in android 11 as to how an app accesses it. Now apps can't access other storage other than their own data directories. Some apps which can't work without accessing the file system like File manager need to have **all file access permission**.
Your app is crashing in android 11, most probably because it doesn't have permission to write on storage.
For further info - [Read here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: So do you have any knowledge which permission or any piece of code should i add ? Any Idea @Praveen

Comment: Try this https://www.raywenderlich.com/10768834-scoped-storage-tutorial-for-android-11-deep-dive 

You can use the Storage Access Framework (SAF) to access storage, search for how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

`getFilesDir()` helps me:

```
new RealmConfiguration.Builder().directory(    getFilesDir()    )...
```

change `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to `getFilesDir()`